# Multiple XML data in datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

My query to a large Xml Database

```
 var query = DOC.Descendants("entry").Where(f => f.Element("url").Value.Contains("example"));
```

returns multiple xml Data
I display the data using a richtextbox

```
foreach (XElement result in query)
{richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + result; }
```

One xml data looks like this:

```
<entry>
<url><![CDATA[http://triada.kh.ua/made/?email=abuse@example.com</url>
<phish_id>3779980</phish_id>
<phish_detail_url>http://www.phishtank.com/phish_detail.php?phish_id=3779980</phish_detail_url>
<details>
<detail>
<ip_address>93.190.41.34</ip_address>
<cidr_block>93.190.40.0/21</cidr_block>
<announcing_network>6849</announcing_network>
<rir>ripencc</rir>
<detail_time>2016-01-24T01:00:58+00:00</detail_time>
</detail>
</details>
<submission>
<submission_time>2016-01-22T22:42:56+00:00</submission_time>
</submission>
<verification>
<verified>yes</verified>
<verification_time>2016-03-28T14:15:01+00:00</verification_time>
</verification>
<status>
<online>yes</online>
</status>
<target>Internal Revenue Service</target>
</entry>
```

As you can see its rather complex,some of the Children nodes have other children that contain values. My Questions are :

1. How can i put all this values neatly into a Datagridview.
2. There are multiple of this exact format of xml.How can i add each as a new column in the Datagrid.
3. How can i prevent performance issues as my queries may return more than 50 of this xml data.

   Please Help me.Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Try using DataSet.ReadXml method : DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ds.ReadXml(filename); datagridview1.DataSource = ds.Table[0];  Also try ds.Table[1];  Not sure which will contain more data.

Comment: They both contain data but i want all of it on one table